# Create ColorCube CIFilter

Tags: ios, filter, cifilter, ciimage

I want to create ColorCube CIFilter for my app and i found documentation on apple site here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html .

Also i post code here,

```
**//Allocate memory **
**const unsigned int size = 64;**
**float *cubeData = (float *)malloc (size * size * size * sizeof (float) * 4);**
float rgb[3], hsv[3], *c = cubeData;

 // Populate cube with a simple gradient going from 0 to 1
for (int z = 0; z < size; z++){
    rgb[2] = ((double)z)/(size-1); // Blue value
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++){
        rgb[1] = ((double)y)/(size-1); // Green value
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x ++){
            rgb[0] = ((double)x)/(size-1); // Red value
            // Convert RGB to HSV
            // You can find publicly available rgbToHSV functions on the Internet
            rgbToHSV(rgb, hsv);
            // Use the hue value to determine which to make transparent
            // The minimum and maximum hue angle depends on
            // the color you want to remove
            float alpha = (hsv[0] > minHueAngle && hsv[0] < maxHueAngle) ? 0.0f: 1.0f;
            // Calculate premultiplied alpha values for the cube
            c[0] = rgb[0] * alpha;
            c[1] = rgb[1] * alpha;
            c[2] = rgb[2] * alpha;
            c[3] = alpha;
            c += 4; // advance our pointer into memory for the next color value
        }
    }
}
```

i want to know what they take size=64 wand what the mean of that bold line in code?

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Simple, cube is made up of cube of square, square has 4 edges so cube of 4 is 64.

Comment: ok got it,but what the alloc cubeData like this?